# Data Validation for Sheet1 from Sheet2 list

Tags: google-sheets, data-validation

I'm trying to figure out how to validate data entries in one column on sheet 1 from a database I created in sheet 2. In column A sheet 1 the user is allowed to type in a string, upon completion it should check column A of sheet 2 and make sure its a valid entry and if not ask the user to re-enter the string.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

- **you can set up data validation from the range where you have your list of entries:**

[image]